# ExtJS 4 Submit form using model proxy

Tags: forms, rest, extjs, extjs4, extjs-mvc

is it possible to submit a extjs 4 form using the proxy of a model/store. I want to use the submit action for remote validation reasons. I want to use the rest proxy configuration from the model, so that I can a avoid configuring the database/server connection twice.

Thx for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your form exactly represents one instance of your model, why are you using form submit and not `model.save();` or `store.sync()`? These methods were designed for working with your data model and take advantage of all the cool built in capabilities of ExtJS data.

In the [documentation for Ext.data.Model](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.data.Model) under the subheading "Using a Proxy" there are examples for the various operations you may want to perform (GET, PUT, POST, DELETE - aka load, save, save, destroy).

You can then attach some callbacks to the model.save() method so you know if the operation succeeded or failed (perhaps due to server side validation).

Here's an Sencha Forums post talking about your specific use case: [ExtJS 4 Sync and success/failure processing](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?137580-ExtJS-4-Sync-and-success-failure-processing)

The summary is that if your server side validation returned an error with JSON content something like:

```
{ "success": "false", "message": "Error message goes here." }
```

Then you can save your model and catch the failure response and use that extra message JSON element to alert the user why it failed server side validation. Of course you could return a more detailed JSON message if you like, but this proves the concept. Extend to suite your application.

```
myExtModelInstance.save({
    success: function(rec, op) {
        // do something
    },
    failure: function(rec, op) {
        // Lets show a message for the failure with the 
        // content from the server's returned failure JSON
        Ext.Msg.alert("Failed",op.request.scope.reader.jsonData["message"]);
    }
});
```